LazyColumn and Constraint in JetPack Compose
I am setting up a list based design using jetpack compose + constraint in that but I am facing some issue with the constraint link as it won't work properly when it is linked to parent.
Here is my code
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ProductCard(product:ProductModel){
    ElevatedCard(
        onClick = { },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp, top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = Color.White,
        )
    ) {
        ConstraintLayout{
            val (productImage,productName,productCategory,
                productPrice,ratingPrice) = createRefs()

            AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(product.productImage)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                contentDescription = null,
                placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.user),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(productImage) {
                        start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 10.dp)
                        top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 15.dp)
                        end.linkTo(productName.start)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    }
                    .width(72.dp)
                    .height(72.dp)
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(productName) {
                        top.linkTo(productImage.top)
                        start.linkTo(productImage.end, margin = 10.dp)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end,margin = 10.dp)
                        width = Dimension.wrapContent
                    },
                text = product.productName,
                fontFamily = notoSansFontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(productCategory) {
                        top.linkTo(productName.bottom, margin = 5.dp)
                        start.linkTo(productName.start)
                        width = Dimension.wrapContent
                    },
                text = product.productCategory,
                fontFamily = notoSansFontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                fontSize = 15.sp,
            )

            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(ratingPrice){
                    top.linkTo(productCategory.bottom, margin = 5.dp)
                    start.linkTo(productName.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = product.productPrice,
                    fontFamily = notoSansFontFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    color = Color.White
                )

                Text(
                    text = "Rating : ${product.productRating}",
                    fontFamily = notoSansFontFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                    color = Color.Yellow,
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)
                )
            }

Inside Row I updated the code added up the arrangement, the result is different for all the cards. It is very straight Row should be linkTo startOf productName and endOf parent. Don't know why it us behaving different for each card. Check out the image, it is rendering same in physical and emulator device.


I am not sure I understood what you want to achieve. Do you want to align the blue Text to the left and the red Text to the right?

The Blue is a Row, inside which I have 2 Text I want one on right and red one left. I used Constraint but it didn't worked. Then I used Row to fillMaxWidth set background as blue color. I want first Text to be startAsStart Image of and second Text endAsEndOf parent.

Thanks for the clarification. I added an answer below, if it resolves your problem, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

Please try to add the horizontalArrangement parameter to the Row and make sure the ConstraintLayout uses fillMaxWidth():
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()  // add this line
) {

    //...

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,  // add this line
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(ratingPrice){
            top.linkTo(productCategory.bottom, margin = 5.dp)
            start.linkTo(productName.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        }
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        //...
    }
}

You will also have to change your productName and productCategory Composables. You can make sure the text aligns to the left by using a combination like this:
Text(
     modifier = Modifier
         .constrainAs(productName) {
             //...
             width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
         }
         //...
     ,
     textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
     //...
}


I updated my question with your suggestion and uploaded new image, after adding arrangement in the Row every card behave differenlty.

@Dnveeraj I edited my answer, please have a look.

I didn't understood reconfigure. productName and productCategory already configured on top. how to reconfigure them again ?

@Dnveeraj With reconfigure I meant that you need to change the code that you already have. I edited my answer to make that more clear. So 1) add fillMaxWidth to ConstraintLayout, 2) add horizontalArrangement to Row, and 3) change Text Composables if needed. Please let me know if my code worked for you.

Yeah reconfiguration worked. It seems in compose setting constraint for two compose also interrelated to each other's width either it is wrap content or fill to constraint.
